# Drupal: I need to display the user name in a block

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a Drupal module to display the user name in a block, when he is logged in ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Creat a new block.
- Format: PHP code

Block Body:

```
<? 
global $user;
print $user->name;
?>
```

Comment: For completeness:  if you cannot choose 'php code' as a block content filter, go to your Modules and enable 'PHP Filter'.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7, using a custom module named YOURMODULE:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function YOURMODULE_block_info() {
  return array(
    'YOURMODULE_logged_in_as' => array(
       'info' => t('Login information ("Logged in as...").'),
       'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function YOURMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ($delta == 'YOURMODULE_logged_in_as') {
    global $user;
    return array(
      'subject' => NULL,
      'content' => t('Logged in as !name', array('!name' => theme('username', array('account' => $user)))),
    );
  }
}
```